# Extract day,month,time of the day from date using Pig

Tags: apache-pig

**input format** : Mon, 09/20/10 01:04 PM

Have to extract Day,Month,Time of the day.
I'm aware of the inbuilt functions `GetDay`,`GetMonth`,e.t.c

but im getting this following error while using it

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.b
>   uiltin.GetMonth as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an
>   explicit cast.

even tried `GetMonth(ToDate(date))...` but of no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple usage of ToDate() assumes the date string to be in ISO format, which yours is not. You need to provide the function with a format string that describes your date format. See https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#to-date for details.

Something like

```
ToDate(date, 'E, M/d/Y K:m a')
```

should work.

Comment: thanks, that gave an idea on how to solve this, though still im getting error as ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B. Backend error : Invalid format: "date". just i will go through the different formats specified in the link. My input  (Mon, 09/20/10 01:04 PM) is exactly as yours specified format donno , why itsn't taking  and telling invalid format